# django-tables2 customize table visualization

Tags: python, html, django, django-tables2

I am working on a web app with Django (first time using this) and I have successfully rendered a table with django-tables2 and it looks like this:

```
Sequence     Epitope     Score

sequence1    name1       0.5    
sequence1    name2       0.7
sequence2    name1       0.4
sequence2    name2       0.2
...          ...         ...
```

But I would like to switch the columns and rows to get it to look like:

```
Sequence     name1     name2     ...
sequence1    0.5       0.7       ...
sequence2    0.4       0.2       ...
...          ...       ...
```

Is there a way to change this **without** changing my models?
I have been searching for a while now but I can't find a way to change this.  Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my table from tables.py

```
class CSVTables(tables.Table):

class Meta:
    model = CSV_Results
    attrs = {
        'class': 'output_table',
        'th': {'class': 'output_table_header'}
        }
    template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
    fields = ('TCRsequence', 'Epitope', 'Score')#,"Submission_ID")
```

The model is linked to a form, depending on the input from the user, there could be 10 names in 'Epitope', 50 or just 2,... . 
My model:

```
class CSV_Results(models.Model):
TCRsequence = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Epitope = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Score = models.FloatField()
Submission_ID = models.ForeignKey('Info_Submission',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "CSV_results"
```

My views.py:

```
table = CSVTables(CSV_Results.objects.filter(Submission_ID__Submission_ID__exact=submission_id))
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 50}).configure(table)
```

And in my html I just rendered the table with:

> {% render_table table %}

Thanks!

Comment: Using django-tables2 here slows you down. You need to create your CSVTables class on the fly because you don't know the column selection of the user. So my advice is to write the query and javascript by hand. django-tables2 is not build with your request in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed set of columns which are not generated dynamically, define table as below and do not associate it with model

```
class CSVTables(Table):
   sequence = Column(verbose_name='Sequence')
   name1 = Column(verbose_name='Name1')
   name2 = Column(verbose_name='Name2')
```

Then iterate over queryset objects to generate list of  dictionary objects matching to table, which will be passed as argument during table initialization. Each dictionary object should be of format

```
{ 'sequence' : 'xxxx',
   'name1' : 'yyy',
   'name2' : 'zzz'}
```

**Update:**

django-tables2 will not suite for dynamic columns generation. For Dynamic columns client side rendering is a better option. There are couple of JS libraries like [datatables](https://datatables.net/) might help at client side. A django view app for datatables is [django-datatable-view](https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view), but I have  not tried the dynamic tables in this app. If not, a simple view which can serialize the JSON data as per datatables requirement, which is quite simple, is all  what is needed.

Comment: But the only problem is that the amount of names (name1,name2...) depends on the input of the user (from a form). So for one user it is possible that there are only 2 names (name1 and name2) submitted, but for another user it is possible that there are 50 different names submitted through the form (name1,name2,..., name50) and then the table has to contain 50 columns (1 for each name). Can you make the new tables (not associated with the model) dynamic?

Comment: Then django-tables2 may not be good solution. A client side library like data tables can create dynamic tables from passed JSON. I will update my answer.